# Searching all tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a little problem. I have 2 tables in my database:

`servico`,  with id, nome, profissao (plumber, electrician,e tc), data and local.

`canalizador`, with id, nome, profissao (only plumber), data and local.

I have this code so that I can get to the "canalizador" table:

```
mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM canalizador WHERE profissao LIKE '$profissao'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$casaArray = array();
```

But I need a code where I can search all the tables like the "canalizador" table by just pressing the button of each career(profissao) in the menu. If I do this:

```
mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM canalizador, carpinteiro WHERE profissao LIKE '$profissao'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$casaArray = array();
```

I have this error:

> Column 'profissao' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: That error cause is that "profissao" does exist inside both table, you can use canalizador.profissao to tell sql which table (you can use an AND condition to tell it to both table for example)

Comment: But why do you have two tables with the same columns and very similar contents?

Comment: 1) You have a table design problem, because you haven't followed good normalization practices.  In most well-designed systems, there will only be one table linking names to professions.  2) You are wide open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Fix your query or be subject to data theft or worse.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `UNION ALL` with the two tables, use `LIKE` in the result (as a derived table):

```
select id, nome, profissao, data, local 
from
(
select id, nome, profissao, data, local from servico
UNION ALL
select id, nome, profissao, data, local from canalizador
) dt
where dt.profissao LIKE '$profissao'
```

Alternatively, as suggested by AsConfused, just a `UNION ALL`:

```
select id, nome, profissao, data, local from servico
where profissao LIKE '$profissao'
UNION ALL
select id, nome, profissao, data, local from canalizador
where profissao LIKE '$profissao'
```

Comment: You involved 3 selects when 2 would suffice. Explain would show degradtion of performance. Which could be significant considering the two inside filter nothing and bring it all then at end it says i only want this filter

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I don't know how MySQL optimizes queries like this. I'll add your suggested version too.

Comment: The 2 inside are tablescans. The outer dt is derived and therefore cannot use an index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM canalizador c1, carpinteiro c2 WHERE c1.profissao LIKE '$profissao'";
                                                          // ^ c1 or c2 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$casaArray = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all is bad practice to use comma separated tables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM canalizador, carpinteiro, etc...
```

You need to use `JOINS` and list column names in SELECT clause like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM canalizador can 
JOIN carpinteiro car ON can.Id = car.Id
```

Then specify from which table you want to use `profissao` column

```
WHERE can.profissao LIKE '$profissao
```

Comment: U sure u want your first line to say that? Or your last

Answer (score 0):

As first option you can give your column name an **alias** with `AS` keyword, i.e:

```
SELECT canalizador.column AS col1, carpinteiro.column AS col2 
FROM canalizador, carpinteiro WHERE profissao LIKE '$profissao'
```

As second option you can rework your SQL query and use MySQL `JOIN` to combine multiple table results, read more about how to join tables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and more general information [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Comment: Better to qualify as table.column!